# Media query for HDPI and MDPI Laptop screens not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to apply different property to an element for HDPI and MDPI screen.
I tried following code but it works only for HDPI not for MDPI.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .myClass {
    margin-left: 34%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 899px) and (min-width: 500px) {
  .myClass {
    margin-left: 43%;
  }
}
```

Here media screen min-width 990px(HDPI) is working but for other it is not working. How should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* (ldpi) Android*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75){
  /* CSS  */
}

/* (mdpi) Android*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 800px) {
  /* CSS  */
}

/* (hdpi) Android*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5){
  /* CSS  */
}
```

[Reference 1](http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/using-media-queries-for-multi-platform)

[Reference 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#resolution)

Comment: I was expecting answer for Hdpi and Mdpi Laptop screen.. Can u edit the Answer.. Thanks

Comment: This is confusing.. What min-width and max-width should I put for Laptop screen of resolution 1440x900 and 1280x800?

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {..} & media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {..}

Comment: 1200px and 1600px is not working.. as they are height not width

Comment: @vidal..so interchange the values..with actual width values you want....

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is (.scss)

```
  @media only screen and (min-height: 500px) and (max-height: 800px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```